# How to properly fix 'no-implicit-any' when accessing unknown object member?

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

In a large project, I have a standard reporting module that displays in a grid data, and where the user can define filters and sorting.

Because I don't want to replicate logic, I setup a generic filtering function that can accept data from any type and filter options.

Everything is working perfectly, but ESlint is yelling because of the `any` usage.

Here's a simplified [reproductible code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkDtQWwewCYFcA2BTUSAuBLFOsBPAWACgyyiAHDAJzSrlqwGUsBDLDAXlAG8yoUADM8XWgHloALlABnLLRyQA5gBpBIsWloA1diiQZZCparIBfCqQDGcSAq0pxAEU7sACvQQ4bnHqAAFLRwAO6gsuyQhGqgAG44aKESVLj2chGg9IzMbP4AlNwAfALkpEJ2DligCO4A0miEoLwJSSlpDgB0os46UqDsGQDWjXDCA9EA3NYV6dVxBkYAKnAAwgAWaDZDzVlhANq1HA2EALrTZUL0WEi00AuGaCsbW0MA-J1YcGxmKoH5zW4LUSyVSOHS3W0ekWaAulmsIAg0EqciQMGUKlgiFQGAAjJRCDRQB44MpqrxSkIAB6ySBogBGOg05VAhFpDJ0ljhtjmoBUtHYVHWbg4shJZP2p12+00fFANNAAAZYmzQAAmRWgCyxOUKgC0AA4VbJcWqtTr5SbFcrWbJNVZSKdrCjqjZbvRIFgAOICoUAJQYTCw7XBDl2lKc4n6sgARFSY8yhD1xPpHpkY4qY1yyC7Izo0AgfYLhe5dvziyL2JDerRAsEwoUismdJWvAXfP566FYm7aB7vb71gGcsGwel8vluTn0nB0J0UHA-s3vEWhZXJwiwFBQCi0Risch0OqCUTVkgFHAYDpw5pRLQFAA5dhXkyKDGJ0AoQZYJ8v+Rv8xSAsblczdC8r1oStZDPcCdElaVZS0e8f2fNBYwAKTgdZIATT9v1-YxQBjFh0SwdYY21fgkMfVD03QqI0Fwr8aJfYjSPI7U5TvFjCJjTDGNiZiUNYtxnHsCiyCdMpQPdNBPRgr4IOHIMQ3SG8WWXaMiKEgiE1vKFUyMdMSIIcjsx5Ko828BTLxbUteDAxS7I4atxDrEJQkbZdW28DsuC7HtZPk88nNoZTmFUhwJynCy5FnNB50XQJlwLGyIPXSYgA) (actual code contains a lot more rules and complexity, like string normalization and data sorting):

```js
// In module utility

type reportState = {
  filterOn : string,
  filterValue : string
}

const filterDataPredicate = (row : any, viewOptions : reportState)=>{

  const dataKey = viewOptions.filterOn as keyof any;

  const valueToCheck = row[dataKey];

  return valueToCheck?.toString() === viewOptions.filterValue;

}

// In consuming module 1
type Point = {
  x: number,
  y: number
};

const graphData: Point[] = [
  { x: 0, y: 20 }, { x: -8, y: 12 }, { x: 100, y: 0 }
]

const currentGraphReportOptions = {
  filterOn : "x",
  filterValue : "0"
};
const filteredGraphData = graphData.filter((row)=>filterDataPredicate(row, currentGraphReportOptions));


console.log(filteredGraphData);

// In consuming module 2
type Customer = {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string
};

const customerData: Customer[] = [
  { firstName: "John", lastName : "Smith"}, { firstName : "Jane", lastName:"Smith"},{ firstName : "Joe", lastName:"Dalton"}
]

const currentCustomerReportOptions = {
  filterOn : "lastName",
  filterValue : "Smith"
};
const filteredCustomerData = customerData.filter((row)=>filterDataPredicate(row, currentCustomerReportOptions));


console.log(filteredCustomerData);
```

Everything works as expected, except for the ESLint warning :

> warning  Unexpected any. Specify a different type  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any

My IDE (VSCode) suggests me to either replace type by `unknown` or `never`, but none works.

When using `unknown`, `row[dataKey]` is not compiling (`Object is of type 'unknown'.(2571)`), while when using `never`, it tells me `.toString()` is not available on `never` type (`Property 'toString' does not exist on type 'never'.(2339)`).

Is there a clean way to fix that?

PS: if it matters, I enable `strict : true` in my tsconfig.json file, and in my eslint config I have :

```
{
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue (w/o disabling the rule)

The correct type for row object should `Record<string, unknown>`.

I think this is working because my incoming row will be non empty objects and nothing else (no base type, ...). Whatever the object values will be, it's always identified by an object key.

[Updated code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkDtQWwewCYFcA2BTUSAuBLFOsBPAWACgyyiAHDAJzSrlqwGUsBDLDAXlAG8yoUADM8XWgHloALlABnLLRyQA5gBpBIsWloA1diiQZZCparIBfCqQDGcSAq0pxAEU7sACvQQ4bnHqAAFLRwAO6gsgBKaHa0CAA8psrqmJAA1pBhkAB8aqAAbjhooRJUuPZyEaD0jMxs-gCU3NkC5KRCdg5YoAjuANJohKC8hcWl5Q4AdKLOOlIA3NYdFd35BkYAKnAAwgAWMWnD1WEA2r0cA4QAuottQvRYSLTQAAYAJHxrhmhbewcWL2G3BGRRKZRwFWm2j06zQt0s1hAEGgnTkSBgyVgiFQGAAjJRCDRQB44MpurxWkIAB6ySDogBGOg07VAhFpDJ0lnhthWoBUtHYVF2bg4shJZJOVyOJ00fFANNAAAY8mzQAAmRWgCx5OUKgC0AA4VbJcWqtTr5SbFcrWbJNVZSFdrKjujYnvRIFgAOICoXRWpYcYQhxHSlOcRSKoAIipUeZQhm4n032jiqjXLILvDOjQCB9guF7iO-ILIvYUNmtECwTCTWyiZ0Za8ud8-hroTybtoHu9vt2-qYgfBFQaDW5mYqcHQkxQcBUgQb3nzQrLY8RYCgoFR6Mx8GQ6HVBKJ2yQCjgMB0oc0oloCgAcuwLyZFMl46AUOx74+0M+zCoM20WZumeF60GWsgniBOiStKspaLeWAPk+oBRgAUnAuyQHG76foh37RiwGJYLsUbavw8Ffhe0aoewkBoNhH6UT+UaEQQJHanKN5MdRcD0XkjF4U+UZuM49ikWQTqAbyXY9pBWDnjoA7MEGFRXiyi6RrIUYCUhfHXtCyZGARREkQBWaLrmckKWBRa8MB8mgWWFbiNWIShHWi5Nt4rZcO2nbumgnpWaBSlDhMcijuOPIOFOaAznOC7QpZp4OY27hjkAA) :

```js
// In module utility


type reportState = {
  filterOn : string,
  filterValue : string
}

const filterDataPredicate = (row : Record<string, unknown>, viewOptions : reportState)=>{

  const dataKey = viewOptions.filterOn;

  const valueToCheck = row[dataKey];

  return `${valueToCheck}` === viewOptions.filterValue;

}

// In consuming module 1
type Point = {
  x: number,
  y: number
};

const graphData: Point[] = [
  { x: 0, y: 20 }, { x: -8, y: 12 }, { x: 100, y: 0 }
]

const currentGraphReportOptions = {
  filterOn : "x",
  filterValue : "0"
};
const filteredGraphData = graphData.filter((row)=>filterDataPredicate(row, currentGraphReportOptions));


console.log(filteredGraphData);

// In consuming module 2
type Customer = {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string
};

const customerData: Customer[] = [
  { firstName: "John", lastName : "Smith"}, { firstName : "Jane", lastName:"Smith"},{ firstName : "Joe", lastName:"Dalton"}
]

const currentCustomerReportOptions = {
  filterOn : "lastName",
  filterValue : "Smith"
};
const filteredCustomerData = customerData.filter((row)=>filterDataPredicate(row, currentCustomerReportOptions));


console.log(filteredCustomerData);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change that `eslint` rule to `"@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off"`. Then it won't complain about it anymore. You can also change it to `warning` if you want it to warn you but not throw an error.

Comment: I want to keep this rule on. It improves quality in the large codebase of our project. I know I can "ignore" the error locally, but I'd like to know if there's a proper way to get rid of the error.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to 'get rid of the error'. You can either disable the error check as outlined in my answer, or you can do a one line ignore like you mentioned in your above comment.